# Cluster point for complex numbers

Tags: real-analysis

What are the cluster points of the sequence $(i^n+1/2^n)_{n\epsilon N}$ ? $a_{2n}=((-1)^n + 1/2^{2n})$, $(-1)^n$ diverges and $1/2^{2n}$ converges, but the subsequence diverges. Similarly $a_{2n+1}=(i^{2n+1}+1/2^{2n+1})$ diverges, so does that mean there is no cluster point?

Comment: Those are not the only subsequences you can have. What about $a_{4n+1}$?

Comment: $a_{4n+1}=(i+1/2^{4n+1})$ converges to i? and so similarly does $a_{4n}$, $a_{4n+2}$, and $a_{4n+3}$ converge to 1, -1 and -i respectively?

Comment: @112358 Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Let $a_n=i^n+\frac{1}{2^n}$. Note that if $k,r\in\mathbb{N}$,
$$i^{4k+r}=i^{4k}\cdot i^r={(i^4)}^k\cdot i^r={1}^k\cdot i^r=i^r.$$
Now consider the four subsequences, $(a_{kn})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(a_{4k+1})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(a_{4k+2})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$, $(a_{4k+3})_{k\in\mathbb{N}}$.

Can you take it form here?

P.S. Since $1/2^n\to 0$ and $i^0=1$, $i^1=i$, $i^2=-1$ and $i^3=-1$, it follows that the cluster points of the sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ are $\pm 1$ and $\pm i$.